# how to get first and last name from windows authentification

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new with asp.net mvc and need to get the users' first and last name display in _Layout view.

I have the user name without the domain name data via this line

```
@Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Substring(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1)
```

I saw one solution which looks like -

add reference `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
    var firstName = principal.GivenName;
    var lastName = principal.Surname;
}
```

add a Razor helper like so:

```
@helper AccountName()
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
        @principal.GivenName @principal.Surname
    }
}
```

but there is no controller for _Layout.cshtml and if i put it directly in razor it is not working either.

Any help would be appriciated !!

Comment: What about to use session...

Comment: but where the logic witten? i need to display it in _Layout.cshtml..
and how can i get the first and last name from session? as far as i know i can get  key\username\computer name ...

Comment: You can store first and last name in session variable after login. I mean in Login Action method. Then you can access those in your _Layout page.

Comment: i dont have login action method since it is intranet, so i have windows authentication which login automatically

Comment: Then you can write in your landing/home page. Then you can retrieve in your layout page.

Answer (score 2):

ok, so after a lot of thinking of how Razor works i find a solution, 
in the _Layout.cshtml -

```
<head>
    @using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
</head>

<body>
    @{
        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
        var firstName = principal.GivenName;
        var lastName = principal.Surname;
    }
<p class="navbar-brand"> @firstName @lastName </p>
</body>
```

hope it will be helpful.